# MSAL ssoSilent and 3rd Party Cookies

Tags: single-spa, msal

I have a Single-SPA with multiple micro-apps using MSALv2.  They each use the same client id to validate user is authenticated using silent sso.  That said, they all are some form of the same domain but different sub-domains.  xxx.yyy.same.somedomain.com vs aaa.bbb.same.somedomain.com vs asdf-sdfg.dfgh.erty.same.somedomain.com

Yet if 3rd party cookies are blocked the single-spa's fail to load.  My understanding is that for silent SSO that MSAL uses a hidden iframe. Is that iframe an external url like microsoft?  I'm just trying to understand why the cookie issue.  Also, it only occurs for some of the micro-apps but not all of them, so its really throwing me for a loop.

Comment: my understanding that different subdomains still registered as 1st party cookies

Comment: You might want to raise this question in the MSAL repo as a discussion or an issue.